# Using Promise and async together

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am kind of new to Node.js and I am trying to understand the idea of using Error handling and waiting to get response correctly.

So I am requesting some data from a webpage and then if I get the data its done but If not then it should go and retry it again and gain until max number is reached.

here is my code:

```js
const getData = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'my url',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        }
        function callBack(error, response) {
            if (!error) {
                let data = response.data;
                return resolve({ success: true, data: data, statusCode: response.statusCode })
            } else {
                return reject({ success: false, error: error })
            }
        }
        request(options, callBack)
    })
}
```

```js
let count = 1
const retry = async (max, next) => {
    let result = await getData(url)
    if (result.code !== 200) {
        while (count < max) {
            console.log('failed, retrying... ' + count);
            count = count + 1
            retry(max, next);
        }
        return next('max retries reached', null)
    }
    console.log('success');
    next(null, result.data)
}
```

So after this part I am trying to run retry until I get the data for 5 times like:

```js
retry(5, 3000, function (err, data) {
   if (!err) {
      return data
   }
   return err                                
})
```

but running retry function like this means I do not wait until I get data. How can I use the idea of try/catch or .then when calling retry function so that it waits for my data to come?

Comment: In `retry()` you have both iteration (a `while` loop) and recursion (retry calls itself). Either (written correctly) will do the job, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `retry()` you need to iterate (with a while loop) *or* recurse (with retry() calling itself), but not both.

If you choose to recurse, then be sure to `return retry()`.

Passing a `next` function isn't necessary as `retry()` will return a promise. Therefore, in retry's caller, you can chain `retry().then(...)` or the async/await equivalent.

Something along these lines should do it :

```
const retry = async(max, count) => {
    count = count || 0;
    let result;
    if(count >= max) { // top test; ensures that getData() isn't run even if say `retry(5, 10)` was accidentally (or deliberately) called.
        throw new Error('max reached'); // will not be caught below and will terminate the trying.
    }
    try {
        result = await getData(url);
        if(result.code !== 200) {
            throw new Error(`getData() was unsuccessful (${result.code})`); // will be caught and acted on below
        }
        return result.data; // will bubble upwards through the call stack to retry's original caller
    }
    catch(error) {
        // all errors ending up here qualify for a retry
        console.log(error.message, `retrying... (${count})`);
        return retry(max, count + 1); // recurse
    }
}

// call as follows
retry(5).then(function(data) {
    // work with `data`
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    // take remedial action, rethrow `error`, or do nothing
});
```

In practice, you would probably choose to introduce a delay between retries to give the data source more time to change state.